# debian: does apt-get support 302 redirects?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

Will *apt-get* follow 302 redirects if instructed?

**Clarifications**

I have my own DEBIAN repositories and I am in the process of evaluating if I can "virtually consolidate" all of them to one.  For this, I need to understand if client side apt-get can follow 302 redirects since the "virtual repo" would use this "trick" to have apt-get fetch .deb package from different places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since apt 0.7.21 (14th April 2009) it does, prior to that it didn't.

(The reason was that some mirrors of Debian ran apache with the mod_spelling module, which would redirect non-existent urls to similarly spelled ones -- so asking for dpkg_1.0-2_i386.deb on an out of date mirror might get you a redirect to dpkg_1.0-1_i386.deb)

See [Debian bug #79002](http://bugs.debian.org/79002) for more details if you're interested.

Added: oh, Ubuntu got it earlier: 0.7.20.2ubuntu1 (9th Feb 2009). See [Ubuntu bug#18645](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/apt/+bug/18645)

Comment: FYI: apt in Lenny (5.0) is 0.7.20.  Which means that this is not supported under the stable Debian.

Answer (score -1):

Well apt-get it more of a package handler than URL handler. The repo URLs are passed to apt-get through the distro (software sources in Ubuntu.)
And since the URLs only represent directories in the end...i don't see why 302 redirects wouldn't work in apt-get.

Are you creating or modifying your own repo?